# WSO2 ESB integration with RabbitMQ

Tags: rabbitmq, wso2-esb

I was able to configure the proxy on WSO2 ESB version 4.8.1 with no errors (Except the JMS error, but it looks irrelevant at this point). Here is a configuration xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<proxy xmlns="http://ws.apache.org/ns/synapse"
       name="AMQP1"
       transports="rabbitmq"
       statistics="disable"
       trace="disable"
       startOnLoad="true">
   <target>
      <inSequence>
         <log level="full"/>
         <property name="OUT_ONLY" value="true"/>
         <property name="FORCE_SC_ACCEPTED" value="true" scope="axis2"/>
      </inSequence>
      <endpoint>
         <address uri="rabbitmq:/AMQP1?rabbitmq.server.host.name=localhost&amp;rabbitmq.server.port=5672&amp;rabbitmq.server.user.name=guest&amp;rabbitmq.server.password=guest&amp;rabbitmq.queue.name=queue1&amp;rabbitmq.exchange.name=exchange1"/>
      </endpoint>
   </target>
   <parameter name="rabbitmq.queue.name">queue2</parameter>
   <parameter name="rabbitmq.connection.factory">AMQPConnectionFactory</parameter>
   <parameter name="rabbitmq.exchange.name">amq.direct</parameter>
   <parameter name="rabbitmq.queue.routing.key">queue2</parameter>
   <description/>
</proxy>
```

I’m sending the message from the java client to the queue2 and listen on other client for the queue1. I suppose the message forward is works like this? I do not perform yet any message format changes.
I can see the message arrived on queue2 from the RabbitMQ console, but on the WSO2 console i can see an error:

```
[2015-06-30 11:44:54,920] INFO – CarbonAuthenticationUtil ‘admin@carbon.super [
-1234]’ logged in at [2015-06-30 11:44:54,920+0200]
[2015-06-30 12:07:40,293] ERROR – NativeWorkerPool Uncaught exception
org.apache.axiom.om.OMException: javax.xml.stream.XMLStreamException: ParseError
at [row,col]:[1,23]
Message: Element type “soapenv:Envelopexmlns” must be followed by either attribu
te specifications, “>” or “/>”.
at org.apache.axiom.om.impl.builder.StAXOMBuilder.next(StAXOMBuilder.jav
a:296)
at org.apache.axiom.soap.impl.builder.StAXSOAPModelBuilder.getSOAPEnvelo
pe(StAXSOAPModelBuilder.java:204)
at org.apache.axiom.soap.impl.builder.StAXSOAPModelBuilder.(StAXSO
APModelBuilder.java:154)
at org.apache.axiom.om.impl.AbstractOMMetaFactory.createStAXSOAPModelBui
lder(AbstractOMMetaFactory.java:73)
at org.apache.axiom.om.impl.AbstractOMMetaFactory.createSOAPModelBuilder
(AbstractOMMetaFactory.java:79)
at org.apache.axiom.om.OMXMLBuilderFactory.createSOAPModelBuilder(OMXMLB
uilderFactory.java:196)
at org.apache.axis2.builder.SOAPBuilder.processDocument(SOAPBuilder.java
:55)
at org.apache.axis2.transport.rabbitmq.utils.RabbitMQUtils.setSOAPEnvelo
pe(RabbitMQUtils.java:80)
at org.apache.axis2.transport.rabbitmq.RabbitMQMessageReceiver.processTh
roughAxisEngine(RabbitMQMessageReceiver.java:106)
at org.apache.axis2.transport.rabbitmq.RabbitMQMessageReceiver.onMessage
(RabbitMQMessageReceiver.java:58)
at org.apache.axis2.transport.rabbitmq.ServiceTaskManager$MessageListene
rTask.handleMessage(ServiceTaskManager.java:303)
at org.apache.axis2.transport.rabbitmq.ServiceTaskManager$MessageListene
rTask.run(ServiceTaskManager.java:188)
at org.apache.axis2.transport.base.threads.NativeWorkerPool$1.run(Native
WorkerPool.java:172)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.
java:1145)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor
.java:615)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: javax.xml.stream.XMLStreamException: ParseError at [row,col]:[1,23]
Message: Element type “soapenv:Envelopexmlns” must be followed by either attribu
te specifications, “>” or “/>”.
at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLStreamReaderImpl.next(XMLS
treamReaderImpl.java:598)
at org.apache.axiom.util.stax.wrapper.XMLStreamReaderWrapper.next(XMLStr
eamReaderWrapper.java:225)
at org.apache.axiom.util.stax.dialect.DisallowDoctypeDeclStreamReaderWra
pper.next(DisallowDoctypeDeclStreamReaderWrapper.java:34)
at org.apache.axiom.util.stax.wrapper.XMLStreamReaderWrapper.next(XMLStr
eamReaderWrapper.java:225)
at org.apache.axiom.util.stax.dialect.SJSXPStreamReaderWrapper.next(SJSX
PStreamReaderWrapper.java:138)
at org.apache.axiom.om.impl.builder.StAXOMBuilder.parserNext(StAXOMBuild
er.java:681)
at org.apache.axiom.om.impl.builder.StAXOMBuilder.next(StAXOMBuilder.jav
a:214)
… 15 more
```

Could you please help me!
Thanks in advance,
Ludmila

Comment: I get fwd with this issue, i was following the post https://luispenarrubia.wordpress.com/2015/05/04/how-to-integrate-wso2-esb-and-rabbitmq-using-amqp-transport-part-2/ to resolve the issue og AMQP implementation, so i create the API to send the message to queue and untill this point everything fine, but the messages are not processed correctly, i'm getting an error: org.apache.axis2.AxisFault: Unable to determine content type for message urn:uui
d:62efa40f-f051-455d-9f61-096ae22a6c9e
        at org.apache.axis2.transport.rabbitmq.RabbitMQMessageReceiver.processTh
roughAxisEngine(RabbitMQMessa

Answer (score 0):

Are you setting message content type to text/xml when publishing the messages to your queue? Please go through [1] which explains a real integration usecase (WSO2 ESB + RabbitMQ) with proxy configurations and Java clients to publish/consume messages to/from RabbitMQ.

[1] http://blog.rajkumarr.com/2014/12/wso2-esb-and-rabbitmq.html

Comment: Thank you for the link i get resolved the problem of the communication between the two queue. But now i need to get the messages from the queue and pass them to the REST GET service, i get the message but it is not posted to the service. How i can pass it to the REST? Coul you please suggest me something?

Comment: the part of sending to the queue seems to work but i can't find how to put the parameter to the rest endpoint: <endpoint>
         <address uri="http://localhost:8080/JAXRS-RESTEasy-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT/rest/hello/danger?queryParameter=51"
                  format="soap11"/>
      </endpoint>
i'm getting the queryParameter from application/xml message from the queue as <property name="queryParameter" expression="//queryParameter"/> and i can see it on the wso2 esb log, but do not know how to pass it... Thanks a lot in advance!

Answer (score 0):

You have to create 1 Proxy to pick up the message from the first queue, after reading, in the inSequence you should use the Payload Mediator to create properly your new message to be send to the other queue. In the inSequence add a Send Mediator to pass you recently created payload to the EndPoint of this second queue.

To publish messages to RabbitMQ, just follow the above blog again (https://luispenarrubia.wordpress.com/2015/05/04/how-to-integrate-wso2-esb-and-rabbitmq-using-amqp-transport-part-2). Keep in mind to set properly the Content Type before publishing and consuming, in the blog post explains that.

Regards.

Comment: Thanks for the reply! I have already resolved the problem with two queues. And was asking about the RabbitMQ to REST publishing problem!

Answer (score 0):

I've resolved the issue to publishing from one queue to another using the following proxy definition, if someone could need it.

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<proxy xmlns="http://ws.apache.org/ns/synapse"
       name="AMQPProxyXml"
       transports="rabbitmq"
       statistics="disable"
       trace="disable"
       startOnLoad="true">
   <target>
      <inSequence>
         <log level="full"/>
         <property name="OUT_ONLY" value="true"/>
         <property name="FORCE_SC_ACCEPTED" value="true" scope="axis2"/>
         <property name="rabbitmq.message.content.type"
                   value="application/xml"
                   scope="transport"
                   type="STRING"/>

      </inSequence>
      <endpoint>
         <address uri="rabbitmq:/AMQPProxy?rabbitmq.server.host.name=localhost&amp;rabbitmq.server.port=5672&amp;rabbitmq.server.user.name=guest&amp;rabbitmq.server.password=guest&amp;rabbitmq.queue.name=queue2&amp;rabbitmq.exchange.name=exchange2&amp;rabbitmq.message.content.type=application/xml"/>
      </endpoint>
   </target>
   <parameter name="rabbitmq.queue.name">queue1</parameter>
   <parameter name="rabbitmq.connection.factory">AMQPConnectionFactory</parameter>
   <parameter name="rabbitmq.exchange.name">exchange1</parameter>
   <description/>
</proxy>
```